How to set up git user identity for GitHub Actions and push to protected branch?
I'm trying to set up a workflow for versioning and tagging on my develop branch. Below is my current workflow configuration:
name: Versioning and Tagging
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  version-and-tagging:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set Git User Identity
        run: |
          git config --local user.email <MY_EMAIL>@gmail.com
          git config --local user.name <MY_NAME>

      - name: Bump version
        run: |
          npm version patch

      - name: Push Tag
        run: |
          git push origin HEAD:develop
          git push origin --tags

As you can see in my workflow, I currently set my personal email and name as the git user identity and this setup working fine. However, I've noticed that many users utilize bot emails such as 12345678+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com, github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com, github-actions@users.noreply.github.com, or github-actions@github.com.
My questions are:

What are these email addresses?

Are these email addresses GitHub user accounts like personal accounts?
If not, how can we obtain or configure these bot email addresses for use in our workflows?
If yes, I know we have to enable 'Keep my email addresses private' in Email section of GitHub settings to get an email like ID+USERNAME@users.noreply.github.com.

How can I use this bot email in my organization's repository workflow?
Should I invite this bot account to my organization and grant access to the repository?




Pushing to a protected branch:

My develop branch has a protection rule. How can I configure my workflow to allow this bot account to push to a protected branch?




The committer username and password are completely separate to the credentials used for authenticating with the remote. You could use mickey.mouse@disney.com if you wanted to.

you can goto , settings -> branches -> edit protected branch -> Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests --> add your username which you want to bypass.

Hi @DayanandaDR, thanks for the response. If you want to push to a "protected branch", I can confirm that your solution is working.
